# evaluate expressions in directive attributes

Tags: angularjs, directive

Using AngularJS, I am looking for a way to evaluate expressions with "variables" in a directive's attribute.

For instance, in the *textbox* directive bellow, I want the property *top* to evaluate to the result of "10+index*25"

```
<template resource="api/data.json">
    <!-- usage of textbox component -->
    <textbox name="lblNames" text="name" top="10+index*25" left="11">
</template>
```

*Index* here should be the value of the iteration through ng-repeat in the textBox's Template (see bellow). (Another example : *This* and *lblNames* would refer to and return the component itself.)

```
<!-- template for textBox component -->
<div ng-repeat="row in rows" 
     style="left : {{components.left}}px; 
            top  : {{components.top }}px;">

  {{row[components.text]}}

</div>
```

The best way I have found so far is to use $parse which allows me to evaluate simple expressions such as "1+1" as seen in the code bellow. But how can I evaluate expressions with "dynamic properties" like : 10+index*25 ?

```
angular.module("uvis").directive("uvisTextbox", function($parse, $compile) {
    return { 
    scope : {
      test : '@'
    },
        restrict : 'E',
        require : '^uvisBundle',
        link : function( scope, element, attributes, uvisBundleCtrl) {
      console.log( element );
      uvisBundleCtrl.addComponent({
        text : attributes.text,
                top : $parse( attributes.top )(scope),
                left : $parse( attributes.left )(scope),
        debug : "empty"
          });
            console.log("linked uvisTextbox");
        },
    controller : function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'test';
    }
    };
})
```

To make it easier to understand how the program works, I made JSFiddle here :
https://jsfiddle.net/wxcx7ap3/7/

**update (solution)**

I manage to make it work by evaluating within the textBox template like so :

```
<!-- template for textBox component -->
<div ng-repeat="row in rows" 
     style="left : {{$eval( components.left) }}px; 
            top  : {{$eval( components.top) }}px;">

  {{row[components.text]}}

</div>
```

And of course I update

```
top : $parse( attributes.top )(scope)
```

to

```
top : attributes.top
```

in the directive.

Full example : http://jsfiddle.net/wxcx7ap3/9/

Comment: I get a 

Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%2017-17%20%5B%23%5D&p2=border%3A1px%solid%20%23ccc%3B%20margin-bottom%3A10px%3B%20%20%0A%20%20left%20%3A%2011px%3B%20%0A%20%20top%20%3A%2012px%3B

Comment: @Scottie : Further, the problem is not only in the "style" attribute of the ng-repeat. In the JSFiddle I created, component.top is also null in : <pre>left: {{components.left}}, top: {{components.top}}</pre>  (line 30)

Answer (score 4):

Use interpolation. Angular evaluates expressions within curly braces using the `$interpolate` service, trying to "resolve" all the variables within an expression using the context of the current `scope`.

So in your case:

```
<textbox name="lblNames" text="name" top="{{ 10+index*25 }}" left="11">
```

Angular will search for the `index` value on current scope and calculate the value. Moreover when Angular sees curly braces it places a `watch` on the expression and updates it, every time the value changes.

Comment: I have tried with interpolate but the problem is that the current scope for the "textbox" directive is not the same scope as for all elements generated within the ng-repeat in the textBox's Template (the parameters are passed down to the template from the directive). In the textBox directive, there is no "index" variable. I want index to be the value of the current iteration in the TextBox template.

Answer (score 0):

I evaluate express like this in angular template

```
 <td>{{ ( data.totalDurationOutgoing-0) + (data.totalDurationIncoming-0 ) }}</td>
```